# Discord.js bot can't assign permissions to other users

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

My discord.js bot has administrator permissions, but when I try to assign roles to other members I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')`. I can assign it to myself (server owner) but not anyone else.

```
const member = message.guild.members.cache.get('user id');
member.roles.add('role id')
  .then(role => {
    console.log('added role', role)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.find('user id');
```

Instead of:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.get('user id');
```

Comment: My ide is giving it a warning `Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type (value: GuildMember, key: Snowflake, collection: Collection<Snowflake, GuildMember>) => boolean`. I'm not sure what a `snowflake` is or what it's asking for there. I believe it's asking for a function in .find(), if you know what that issue is.

Comment: Okay, figured it out: `.find(user => user.user.id === 'user id')` However when I do this it's only finding myself (server owner) and the bot. Not another user

Answer (score 0):

use `message.guild.members.fetch('userid')` instead,

```
const member = message.guild.members.fetch('user id');
member.roles.add('role id')
  .then(role => {
    console.log('added role', role)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```